# Как поделиться ссылкой на Android приложение, если оно еще не выставлено в Google Play?

Tags: android, мобильная-разработка

Можно ли получить ссылку на своё android приложение, если ты его еще не выставил в Google Play, но хочешь скачать себе или другу на телефон?

Answer (score 8):

Анна, для того чтобы скачать приложение себе или другу скиньте APK файл на облачное хранилище и распространяйте ссылку друзьям, при установке из APK напрямую нужно включить на устройстве установку из неизвестных источников. Другой вариант - купить Аккаунт разработчика в Google Play за 25$, создать там приложение, подписать его электронным ключом, и выложить как закрытую beta версию, и тогда распространять друзьям ссылки на приложения. В таком случае только вы и ваши друзья, которые получили ссылки, смогут воспользоваться вашим приложением.

Comment: Нужно добавить, что при установке из APK напрямую нужно включить на устройстве установку из неизвестных источников. Но, вообще вариант с закрытой альфой или бетой в Google Play в подобных случаях самый правильный.

Comment: Вариант с выкладыванием апк на сервер или его рассылкой неудобен тем, что каждый раз при новой версии придется каждому об этом говорить и каждому придется снова вручную скачивать и устанавливать.

Comment: @Эникейщик так есть вариант с выкладыванием на Google Play)) но затратный. Пусть выбирают какой лучше.

Comment: Я просто рассказал о возможных неудобствах первого варианта :)

Answer (score 1):

Google предоставляет удобные средства для тестирования приложений. Воспользуйтесь "внутренним тестированием" и внесите до 100 адресов учетных записей. Ссылка на скачивание вам будет предоставлена.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто Вот код вашей будущей ссылки на Google Play когда вы его опубликуете. Пока вы не опубликуете приложение в Google Play ссылка не будет действительна. Ссылка в Google Play состоит из `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id= + appPackageName` последние это адрес который Вы вводили при создании проекта.

```
    public static void shareApp(Activity activity) {
            try {
                final String appPackageName = activity.getPackageName();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.share)
                        + " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Есть возможность скачать приложение через интернет с файлообменика.
Просто скиньте скомпилированый файл на него. 
Скомпилированый файл можно найти по `Ваш проект\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app_debug.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё один вариант, на данный момент является бесплатным, если вам нужно именно груповое тестирование то можно так же воспользоваться ещё [beta от Fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/overview.html)

Многие прикручивают крашлитику от данной компании не зная о продукте "Beta", а она позволяет рассылать приложение по списку електронных адресов, а делается это установкой плагина в студии и просто перетягиванием билда в плагин (там есть кнопка поделиться именно в этот скрин и нужно отправить ваш билд). На этапе тестирования отличный вариант. Но работа с GooglePlay как было сказано выше/ниже является самый правильный.